# What could be user experience when there is error in loading error page?

Tags: reactjs, error-handling, frontend

I'm designing for error handling in our PWA app. We want to handle all client side errors and fallback to error page. The content of this error-page comes from an API call as these are translated in local language.

I've a question about scenario where there could be error in client side data fetching for the data that is needed for error page. What could be our default behavior? Should I put default English language content (for global markets), for cases where there are some errors in fetching data for error page?

Answer (score 0):

You could have a static 404 Page as a backup and navigate to it if there is an error in the response.

```
ErrorComponent.js

getError = () => {
  getErrorData().then(res => {
    //Do something with the response
  })
  .catch(err => {
    //Navigate to a default 404 page
    window.location.href = '/defaulterror';
  })
}
```